# Special case of 3DES

Tags: des, key-size, 3des

3DES uses EDE as it is backward compatible to single DES, but consider the following case $K_1$=$K_2$=$K_3$ which one is more secure EDE or EEE.

Comment: Compatibility always win.

Comment: Actually, 3DES EEE mode is also backwards compatible to DES, because of the DES weak keys...

Comment: Poncho's obseravation is that EEE mode is backwards compatible to DES when we set $K_1=K$ and $K_2=K_3=\mathtt{0x0101010101010101}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EEE with $K_1$=$K_2$=$K_3$ is measurably less insecure than EDE with $K_1$=$K_2$=$K_3$, because the former has 48 rounds, but the later reduces to just one encryption E, thus 16 rounds. Two consequences:

1. This makes brutes force require 3 times more rounds, thus adds about $\log_2(3)\approx 1.58$ bit of practical security against brute force (security in bits grows as the base-2 log of the computational effort); however that remains way too low, and was so [even in 1999](https://w2.eff.org/Privacy/Crypto/Crypto_misc/DESCracker/HTML/19980716_eff_des_faq.html). Brute force is the typical attack against single DES, and works fine including for EEE with 3 equal keys.
2. This regains up to like a dozen bits of security that otherwise might be lost to cryptographic weakness of DES, beyond its low key size.

On the second point: assuming $2^{42.5}$ known plaintexts and as many DES, [implementations](https://crypto.junod.info/lincrypt.pdf#page=57) of Mitsuru Matsui's *Linear Cryptanalysis Method for DES Cipher* (in [proceedings of EuroCrypt 1993](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-48285-7_33)) break 16-round DES with excellent odds and thousand times less work than brute force, but not 48 rounds (and I do not see that subkeys of rank equal modulo 16 being equal can help much).

Note: Linear Cryptanalysis of 16-round single-DES could be the least computationally costly attack in CTR or OFB [mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Common_modes); but in many other modes, as pointed in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/40438/555#comment92305_40440), $2^{42.5}$ known plaintexts by itself allows recovery of a sizable fraction of other plaintext, thus linear cryptanalysis is impractical.

Comment: *sizably* more secure, or *slightly* more secure???  IMHO, making the effective key size 1.5 bits larger against brute force is 'slightly'...

Comment: To my ear (as a native speaker), sizably connotes 'of a significant size', and (again, IMHO) the advantage of EEE in this case is actually quite small (yes, it foils Matsui's attack; that's not much of a practical concern, because you need far beyond the birthday bound of ciphertext/plaintext; brute force is a more valid concern, and EEE makes it only slightly harder...)

Comment: Please just make sure that no one misunderstands this to mean that it is secure at all. DES can be broken very quickly today at not a high cost. So, being more secure in the realm of easy to break is not something that anyone should rely on for anything.

Comment: @fgrieu can you elaborate how come $\log_23$